# Check for multiple maximum dictionary values and output the keys accordingly

Tags: python, list, if-statement, dictionary

I am working on a programme which needs to check the sum of the input of 4 sides against each other and output something according to the highest sum. I have made an "algorithm" using `if` and `elif` statements which works but the problem is that it's about 250 lines of code long. So I started working on a different (proper) way of checking these variables against each other and I created the code below. The only problem is that this code doesn't work if 2 or 3 of the sums are the same. This is due to the use of the `max()` function which only outputs one of the maximum value's. Now I was wondering if there was a way to make this so if for example: the `sum_right` and `sum_left` were the same it would output both the strings/keys  `'left'` and the string `'right'`. So I can check and then choose which of the sides to execute. So far in browsing this forum and going through the python documentation I haven't found an answer. Many thanks in advance!

```
# numbers separated by comma's

a = raw_input('Right').split(',')
b = raw_input('Left').split(',')
c = raw_input('Front').split(',')
d = raw_input('Back').split(',')

sum_right = sum(map(int, a))
sum_left = sum(map(int, b))
sum_front = sum(map(int, c))
sum_back = sum(map(int, d))

sum_input_list = {'right': sum_right, 'left': sum_left, 'front': sum_front, 'back': sum_back}

side = [(value, key) for key, value in sum_input_list.items()]
max_side = max(side)[1]

if max_side == 'right':
    print 'do something right'
elif max_side == 'left':
    print 'do something left'
elif max_side == 'front':
    print 'do something front'
elif max_side == 'back':
    print 'do something back'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from from collections import defaultdict

sum_right = sum(map(int, raw_input('Right').split(',')))
sum_left = sum(map(int, raw_input('Left').split(',')))
sum_front = sum(map(int, raw_input('Front').split(',')))
sum_back = sum(map(int, raw_input('Back').split(',')))

# create a dict to keep these values
_vals = {
    "right": sum_right,
    "left": sum_left,
    "front": sum_front,
    "back": sum_back,
}

# create a default dict, whose default value is an empty list. that means, when you create a new key in the dict, its value will set to an empty list
final_vals = defaultdict(list)
for direction, value in _vals.items():
    final_vals[value].append(direction)  # create keys from values and add each direction to related value
```

You will have a dict like following

```
>> final_vals
>> {5: ["right", "front"],
    4: ["left"],
    1: ["back"]}
```

You can now select biggest value from the keys

```
>> final_vals[max(final_vals.keys())]
>> ["right", "front"]
```

And construct your string from them

```
best_directions = final_vals[max(final_vals.keys())]
print "do something %s" % ", ".join(best_directions)

>> "do something right, front"
```

You will also get rid of usage of `if` blocks for printing directions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the maximum value:

```
maxval = max(sum_input_list.values())
```

Then get the corresponding keys:

```
sides = [k for k, v in sum_input_list.items() if v == max_val]
```